# How to implement "Don't show again" option for Alerts

Tags: android, kotlin, alert

I implemented a "Don't show again" option to my Alert Dialog, but it's not working as intended:
All the other questions are 6-7 years old and in java, and since I am completely new to programming I only know the basics of kotlin as of right now..

```
fun showDialog() {
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater;

    dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null))
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Please always put the total on the bottom right corner. An example is shown below.")
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Alright, got it!",
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, whichButton ->
            pb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
            startActivityForResult(receiptsViewModel.cameraIntent(requireActivity()),REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA)
        })
    val mainView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null)
    checkBox = mainView.findViewById<View>(R.id.checkBox) as CheckBox
    val b = dialogBuilder.create()
    b.show()

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
        if (compoundButton.isChecked) {
            storeDialogStatus(true)
        } else {
            storeDialogStatus(false)
        }
    }
    if (dialogStatus) {
        b.hide()
    } else {
        b.show()
    }
}

private fun storeDialogStatus(isChecked: Boolean) {
    val mSharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("CheckItem", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit()
    mEditor.putBoolean("item", isChecked)
    mEditor.apply()
}

private val dialogStatus: Boolean
    private get() {
        val mSharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("CheckItem",
            AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("item", false)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that the checkbox that you're adding a listener to is for a layout that you're not using. You inflated a layout and set that as your dialog view. Then you inflate a second copy of the layout and set a listener on the checkbox in that unused second layout.

A few other tips, but these aren't things that are preventing it from working. They'll just make your code clearer:

You can chain Builder calls so you don't have to keep putting `dialogBuilder.` and you don't even have to store it in a variable.

`findViewById<View>` can be changed to `findViewById<CheckBox>` so you don't have to cast its result to CheckBox.

You can return early from the function if the dialog isn't needed rather than creating the dialog, showing it, and then immediately hiding it.

Instead of using `if (someBoolean) doSomething(true) else doSomething(false)` you can simplify to `doSomething(someBoolean)`.

```
private fun startCamera() {
    pb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
    startActivityForResult(
        receiptsViewModel.cameraIntent(requireActivity()),
        REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA
    )
}

fun showDialog() {
    if (dialogStatus) {
        startCamera()
        return
    }

    val mainView = requireActivity().layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null)
    checkBox = mainView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
        storeDialogStatus(compoundButton.isChecked)
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(mainView)
        .setMessage("Please always put the total on the bottom right corner. An example is shown below.")
        .setPositiveButton("Alright, got it!") { _, _ -> startCamera() }
        .create()
        .show()
}
```

I also find it odd that you have a property for `checkBox` that couldn't possibly be useful outside this function. You should probably remove the property.

Also, you should look into using DialogFragment instead of a bare Dialog. There are issues with bare Dialogs, such as them disappearing after a screen rotation. The official documentation explains how to use DialogFragment. I will admit, though, that I think DialogFragment is kind of convoluted to use, especially for a new Android programmer.

Comment: Thanks for your great input, really appreciate those kind of tips!
One thing is now tho, that after checking the box for "Don't show again" the camera button doesnt do anything anymore.

Comment: I don’t know which button is the “camera” button.

Comment: Ah sorry, the one that triggers the alert. So the button that first displays the alert and afterwards opens the camera.  With your code the button doesnt do anything after checking  "Dont't show again". It should still open the camera, but not display the alert.

Comment: See the updated code. You can pull that common functionality out into a separate function so you can call it directly if you don't need a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems to be faulty. This piece of code does not work as intended:

```
 if (dialogStatus) {
    b.hide()
} else {
    b.show()
}
```

You should not create the dialog at all if the user has opted out. Please try this modified code:

```
    fun showDialog() {
        if (dialogStatus) {
            return
        }
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater

        dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null))
            .setMessage("Please always put the total on the bottom right corner. An example is shown below.")
            .setPositiveButton("Alright, got it!",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, whichButton ->
                    pb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
                    startActivityForResult(
                        receiptsViewModel.cameraIntent(requireActivity()),
                        REQUEST_CODE_KAMERA
                    )
                })

        dialogBuilder.create().show()

        val mainView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null)
        checkBox = mainView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            if (compoundButton.isChecked) {
                storeDialogStatus(true)
            } else {
                storeDialogStatus(false)
            }
        }
    }
```